# Having several issues with Facebook's Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook comment box on this page: http://8wayrun.tv/

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://8wayrun.tv"
    data-width="100%" data-numposts="20" data-order-by="reverse_time"></div>
```

I am having 3 issues with this comment box.

### 1

If you go to the page, you will see that the facebook comment box is hidden behind a tab. Because the tab is hidden by default as the page loads, the `data-width="100%"` attribute in the comment box code forces the width of the box to be 0 pixels in width; since 100% of hidden is 0px. If you go here instead: http://8wayrun.tv/#facebook, a link which forces the Facebook tab to be open first, you will see that it loads perfectly fine... but issue 1 leads into issue 2...

### 2

The box is not responsive. My entire page is responsive. As you resize the page, the widths of various elements resize with it... except the Facebook box. It seems that the moment the JS loads and the box is placed, FB hard-codes the width at a specific size and it can never be changed. Is there a quick and easy way to make the FB comment box conform to the responsiveness of my page?

### 3

How do I set the height of the comment box? It doesn't seem to stretch the height of my page.

### PS

Is there a way to get the FB comment box to auto-update? So it can be used more as a chatroom than a comment box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issues 1 and 2 with the following code:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) { resizeFacebookComments(); });
$('#fbtab').click(function(e) { resizeFacebookComments(); });

function resizeFacebookComments()
{
    var src   = $('.fb-comments iframe').attr('src').split('width='),
        width = $('#facebook .inner').width()-18;

    $('.fb-comments iframe').attr('src', src[0] + 'width=' + width);
}
```